# Angular Google Map

Tags: angular

I am using angular4 for my project. It requires to add the google map, for this I am using the angular google map (i.e. AGM ) but when I importing AngularCoreModule into my AppModule it is throwing following error:

**ERROR in /home/faraz/Desktop/map-testing/node_modules/@agm/core/services/google-maps-types.d.ts (608,20): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be a constant expression.**

Usinf "typescript": "~2.3.3", "@angular/core": "^4.2.4" and "@agm/core": "^1.1.0"

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ThemeComponent } from './theme/theme.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ThemeRoutingModule } from "./theme/theme-routing.module";
import { AuthModule } from "./auth/auth.module";
import { AmChartsModule } from "@amcharts/amcharts3-angular";
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core'

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ThemeComponent,
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        LayoutModule,
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ThemeRoutingModule,
        AuthModule,
        AmChartsModule,
        ChartsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ModalModule.forRoot(),
        // AgmCoreModule.forRoot(
        //     {
        //         apiKey: ''
        //     }
        // )
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using those outdated versions of typescript and angular? Are you maintaining an old codebase? If not, consider using the latest version of everything. It says here: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-ui/issues/95 you need `typescript` version 2.4 and above to not get this error (it appears to be typescript related, not angular related)

Comment: Yes, I am maintaining an old codebase.
Is there any other syntax to declare the `enum` to get rid of the above error

Comment: Try updating to typescript 2.4 and see if anything breaks. It's a minor version so it's probably gonna be ok.

Comment: after upgrading the typescript version. I got the following error

`ERROR in ./node_modules/@agm/core/fesm5/agm-core.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/operators' in '/home/exsete/Desktop/Exsete/b2b-ui/theme/dist/angular/demo4/node_modules/@agm/core/fesm5'
`

Comment: It would help if you could provide a reproducible example. As it stands, there isn't much I or anyone else can do.